# Power Automate Flow Order

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, power-automate, dataverse

I have a connection from Salesforce to Dataverse table containing information about Signed Contracts. Dataverse table has a ID column that indicates in which order contracts were signed. I have a Power Automate flow "*When a row is created*" --> "*HTTP Request to Sharepoint to check if list with Signed Contract Month already exists*" --> **if yes** -> "*Http request to create an item in that folder*", **if not** --> "*Http request to create a list with the month's name* --> *then create an item in this list*. Everything is working except Power Automate starts to process multiple Dataverse Rows at once, as a result, 2 and more flows indicate that "month" list doesn't exist yet and all those flows create duplicate lists. How do I make sure the flow processes rows one at a time in order in which contracts were signed (ID Column). Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a compelling reason to create individual lists? Consider not creating a new list at all.

You may as well use just one list for all records. Let the list have a column that identifies the "Signed Contract Month" as a piece of metadata, which can be filled in by the flow. You can still access any records for a specific signed contract month by filtering/grouping list items by that column and all data is in one place. At the same time, it doesn't matter how many rows are created simultaneously, since they all just trigger creating a new item in an existing list.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, there is a reason. As I read, a Sharepoint list can have maximum 5,000 records. I retrieve more contracts from SF each month, that is why I am trying to split it into different Sharepoint lists. + I still need an order in which Contracts were added to Dataverse to calculate % of quota achieved while signing a specific contract.

Comment: SharePoint lists can have millions of rows. There are tried and trusted methods to work around the 5000 item limit, which is not per SharePoint list but per items returned in a query. Just use a filter. The order in which contracts were added to the list is reflected in the SharePoint ID of the list item.